# Hiding text if a value is empty

Tags: html

This seems like it should be simple.  I can't seem to figure it out.  I have a list of questions in a user's profile editor.  The users are supposed to answer the question and it will populate in their profile for other's to view.  The problem I have is I can't find a way to hide the question if the user hasn't provided an answer.  Answer1() is the property for their answer.  I cannot find the property for the Question, otherwise it would be much easier. This is what I have for example:

```
 <div>
    <p>This is question1</p> 
        <span data-bind="text: Answer1()"></span>
    <p>This is question2</p>
        <span data-bind="text: Answer2()"></span>
    <p>This is question3</p>
        <span data-bind="text: Answer3()"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: You seem to be using some sort of Javascript library that you don't mention, probably in the genre of AngularJS or Backbone.  This isn't straight HTML, so you'll need to specify what library you're using, and preferably tag the question with it.

Comment: Your question isn't clear. If however you want to hide an element with an empty attribute eg `data-bind=""` then css can do this: `span[data-bind=""]{display:none}`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<div>

    <span id="q1"><p>This is question1</p> 
        <span id="a1" data-bind="text: Answer1()"></span></span>

    <p>This is question2</p>
        <span data-bind="text: Answer2()"></span>
    <p>This is question3</p>
        <span data-bind="text: Answer3()"></span>
</div>

<script>
if(document.getElementById('a1').innerText=="")
{
    document.getElementById('q1').style.visibility='collapse';
    alert("a1 is Empty");
}
</script>
```